# it is strange that the server receive the data more than i had seed from the client

Tags: java

I have send a image that is about 500kb but in the server ,the image that receive is more than 500kb.I wonder that is there any logical problems I had made? the speed of the network is about 100kb/s.

the client

```
package client;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket s = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bo = null;
        BufferedInputStream bi = null;
        try {
            s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",12349);
            bo = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            bi = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("1.jpg"));
            byte [] bys =new byte[1024];
            while((bi.read(bys))!=-1){
                bo.write(bys);
            }
            bo.flush();
            System.out.println("already post the image");
            bi.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }finally{
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("close failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

server

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class sserver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        Socket s = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bo = null;
        BufferedInputStream bs = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(12349);
            s = ss.accept();
            bo = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("2.jpg"));
            bs = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            byte [] bys =new byte[1024];
            while((bs.read(bys))!=-1){
                bo.write(bys);
            }
            bo.flush();
            System.out.println("upload success");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("close failed");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are disregarding the number of bytes read:

```
while((bi.read(bys))!=-1){
  bo.write(bys);
}
```

This means that you always write 1024 bytes to `bo`, even if you read fewer than 1024 bytes from `bi`.

You need to assign the number of bytes read to a variable, and pass that to the write call:

```
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = bi.read(bys))!=-1){
  bo.write(bys, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write exacte byte which you received like below

```
        int len= 0 ;
        while( ( len = bi.read(bys))!=-1){
            bo.write(bys,0, len);
        }
```

Same code change required in both client and server side. I tested at my end and found that both file has same size afterthis change

Answer (score 0):

Your server code is always writing full length of bys array into output stream.

Proper way to do it:

```
byte [] bys =new byte[1024];
while(true) {
  int numRead = bs.read(bys);
  if (numRead == -1)
   break;
   bo.write(bys, 0, numRead);
}
```

Comment: That can't be the proper way to do it - it won't compile.